# PUT on void http-inbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I do not know if I'm following this issue correctly - I send a PUT request via RestTemplate as below:

```
restTemplate.exchange(getBaseUrl() + "/api/getVoid", HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<String>("someMessage"), Void.class);
```

or:

```
restTemplate.put(getBaseUrl() + "/api/getVoid", "someMessage");
```

PUT so it means I do not expect a reply content. My HTTP PUT service is exposed by Spring Integration components:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway supported-methods="PUT" reply-timeout="5000"
                      path="/api/getVoid"
                      request-channel="some-request-channel1" reply-channel="some-reply-channel1">
```

```
<int:channel id="some-request-channel1"/>
<int:channel id="some-reply-channel1"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="some-request-channel1" output-channel="some-reply-channel1" ref="someService"
                   method="restMethodVoid"/>
```

I have a reply channel on my inbound-gateway set but the service that processes the request "returns" void (some PUT operation).

```
@ServiceActivator
public void restMethodVoid(Message<String> request) {
   log.info("DONE! But you will get 500");
}
```

And now the issue - I can see that sending a PUT request into inbound-gateway to be process with void returning method throws 500 Internal Server Error on reply timeout.

Does it mean there is not possibility to send PUT or any other request to SI http inbount gateway "operated by" void service methods?

This is the behaviour in 1.3.2 version but it behaves differently in 1.2.3 for example - the gateway behaviour seems to be the same - it times out but without throwing 500 - just gets back to still waiting request thread and releases it "nicely" (still just on timeout).

I do not see either behaviour perfect, but 1.3.2 is worse because let say I send PUT (or POST with Void.class as return type...) to be processes and it was processed fine - some critical transactional operations were committed and so on - method returned perfectly fine with void but caller gets 500. So this 500 is being propagated this to its caller... ending probably with an error on UI (which can really scare users;)). But everything went fine.

In the 1.2.3 behaviour - even with timeout but the thread could get back to its caller with 200 status, so propagate proper response code next.

Gary, Artem - can you please advice here?

Comment: This is the response from 1.2.3.RELEASE version: `11:16:01.882 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - PUT request for "http://localhost:64526/api/getVoid" resulted in 200 (OK)` (Still it was timeout). And from 1.3.2.RELEASE: `org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error`. Hmmm

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to wither versions 1.2.3 and 1.3.2; those versions don't exist; the behavior was changed (fixed) in version 4.2 - see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to Spring Boot release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [discussion on this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1522#discussion_r50821527).

When the downstream flow returns void you should use an inbound channel adapter, not a gateway; that fix was to correct a problem with the gateway when a timeout occurred - it was incorrectly returning 200, it now returns 500 (by default).

When using a gateway this way, you are incorrectly tying up a web container thread for the default timeout (1s) waiting for a reply that will never be received.

Repeating my full answer from there...

> Gateways are for two-way interaction (request/reply); this fix corrected a problem where, if a timeout occurred, `200 OK` was returned; which was incorrect.
>
> You should use an `<http:inbound-channel-adapter/>` if you never expect a reply (such as in your case). Channel adapters are used for one-way interactions with the message flow (although in this case, a 200 OK is sent to the caller). One-way in this context means the flow doesn't return a reply.
>
> In fact, this fix has simply exposed a bug in your configuration; before this change, the thread would be suspended for 1 second (the default reply-timeout) after the flow completes (waiting for a reply). This means that all your requests take 1 second longer than needed.
>
> The adapter doesn't wait for a reply.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. But still why 500 is returned in case of timeout and not 408 - REQUEST_TIMEOUT?

Comment: 408 is a **client** error (client did not complete the request in time). 5xx are server errors. We chose 500 server error by default, 504 (gateway timeout) has semantics that we can't assume - we don't know if the app is a proxy. The [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-response-statuscode) explains how to change the default 500 with a `reply-timeout-status-code-expression`.

Comment: D'oh.. yeah, I see that everything, as always, carefully thought out ;) Thanks again! 504 doesn't seem to fit neither (not this gateway;))

Comment: Gary, just the last question - when this 200 was returned as a timeout (let say it was set to 10s) - what was happening to the long running job that required more than 10s - was that stopped or just the calling thread was being released with 200 and the job requested was still running on server?

Comment: It depends on whether you hand off to another thread - the gateway timeout only starts when the thread returns to the gateway - if you run the long running job on the web container thread then the timer starts when the job completes; if you hand off to another thread, the timer starts after the handoff.

Comment: So, if I didn't hand off to another thread - it was always long_running_job_time + timeout. So, probably there was no really need for the timeout - it just lengthened the time required to get the timeout error which was really 200, right? Hm.

Comment: Correct; when your task finished, the thread just hung in the gateway for the timeout (default 1s) and finally returned 200. Now, it properly returns 500 due to the timeout; if you change to an inbound channel adapter (which expects no reply), there will be no waiting, and 200 OK is returned (by default), but you could change it to, e.g. 202 Accepted if you want.

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, I have just read about that inbound channel adapter feature [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#http-response-statuscode) - nice.